# Как узнать попадают ли лучи света на объект в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Можно ли определить в тени ли 3d объект, то есть на него не попадает свет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно, нужно копаться в документации юнити по шейдерам https://unity.com/ru/shader-graph

Comment: ну и почитать про основы компьютерной графики

Comment: Если источник света один, экономнее всего будет посчитать по повороту или дистанции.